# Golang cross compile undefined errors

Tags: go, compiler-errors

Probably something obvious, I'm building on OSX trying to build a Linux binary, this same command works on another project but:

```
GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go build -v gitlab.com/project/project-data-convertor
```

returns without error

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -v gitlab.com/project/project-data-convertor
gitlab.com/project/project-data-convertor
# gitlab.com/project/project-data-convertor
./utils.go:253:50: undefined: beamLocation
./utils.go:278:36: undefined: beamLocation
./utils.go:278:50: undefined: beamLocations
./utils.go:278:50: too many errors
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run (GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build) without flag or project ?

Comment: And do you perhaps get the same error if you just run `go build`? (without the environment variables)

Comment: Is it possible that `utils.go` has a build constraint at the top of the file? Something like `//-build linux` or `//+build darwin`? There might be other combinations that produce a working build for OSX and not Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit too late to answer this question but this problem came, on my side, from the import of `C` module. For those who have this problem of cross-platform compilation, check that you don't import `C` module : normally it should work.